# Правильно ли писать-таки «орфоошибка»?

Tags: орфография

Можно сократить *орфографическая ошибка* как *орфоошибка*? Или можно только с песледней буквой — согласной сокращать, как, например, *можваренье*, образованное от *можжевёловое варенье*?